Missing [?] notifications on edits of other users performed on own posts
I've noticed that edits of other users performed on my own posts are not notified here on Italian.SE, despite this happening on other sites across the network.
Is this a site-specific choice?

I receive notifications on edits of my posts, but I'm not sure if I've always received it.

@Charo I do not. I'm sure about this because I've had 3 edits on two of my posts today, one from DaG and  two from you (thanks by the way). In other communities I always receive a notifications tough, and that's why I found this strange. It seems that somehow this something related to my account.

Kos, why don't you try closing your account and then reopen it to see what happens?

@ElberichSchneider I didn't see your comment before, however I've managed to dig this out somehow (see the answer below). Thanks!

Yesterday I transposed the content of this question to Meta.SE as I've experienced the same thing there as well, making what I tought it was a localized issue something network-wide spread: post on Meta.SE.
Turns out, it's status-bydesign; edits "not substantive enough" are simply not notified.
The exact thresholds (modifications to the post's body / modifications to the post's code) over which an edit is notified are community-dependent and not specified; here are the words of Sklivvz ♦ on the very original post:

In order to reduce noise sent to users, we only notify when "substantive" changes are happening on their posts.
There are a few rules in how "substantive" is defined, but typically one of these two should be enough to trigger a message:

the edit in the post body should be over a threshold
the edit in code sections should be over another threshold

The threshold varies from site to site.

